# How can I tell when a remote windows machine has finished starting up?

Tags: windows, remote-access

I need to run some some remote commands on a virtual machine for testing.  But it takes a variable amount of time for the machine to start up.  I don't want want to use an arbitrarily long Sleep to wait to talk to it.
So how can I *remotely* tell when it is *finished starting up* ?

Comment: Just implement a loop that tries to connect to the server periodically and waits for a successful connection before proceeding on to running your remote commands.

Answer (score 0):

What hypervisor is this VM running on?

If it's VMware, you could write a powershell script using the PowerCLI cmdlet: `Wait-Tools`

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Wait-Tools.html

This will pause processing until the VM responds back that vmware-tools are running. Typically, you can assume that *most* functionality will be available at this point. For extra certainty, you can add a timed `sleep` after this is met.

If you're relying on latent services, you could (as EEAA mentioned) write a while-loop that checks for a condition to be true (certain service running, for example) before breaking out of the loop.